# Are Apple Watch step counts saved to Health.app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, health.app, activity.app

I'm thinking about purchasing an Apple Watch. I'm interested in the activity measurements. Currently, I'm using my iPhone to count steps etc. When I connect an Apple Watch to my iPhone and the Apple Watch collects step data, is this step data automatically saved to the Health app on my iPhone (or is it only available in the Activity app, like on the Watch)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you give it permission to access and change data in Health, it's all (steps, walking & running distance, heart rate, active calories, etc.) right there in Health. I know this first-hand, as a proud Apple Watch owner since April 24.[image: Part of my Health dashboard][image: Sources]

Comment: Is the Apple Watch listed under "Sources"?

Comment: Yep. Added a picture of Sources pane to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! One last question: Does the Apple Watch collect only steps or does it also collect distance and floors climbed (like the iPhone 6)?

Comment: Distance, yes. It's right above Steps in the first screenshot. It doesn't track fights climbed, though.